# How do I create thumbnail resizer in my template

Tags: html, css

I was wondering to improve thumbnail size as you see here just in front page of template with some text (See http://shoutingblogger.blogspot.com/) and table via Blogger CSS.

Comment: So improve as in what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your template, change

```
<img src="..." width="200px" height="150px">
```

to

```
<img src="..." width="250px" height="200px">
```

or whatever size you want your thumbnail to be. Your original thumbnail size is already larger than how it is being displayed, so the difference in quality shouldn't be affected much (if any).

Answer (score -1):

it is not not possible in blggoger api to increase thumbnail size because when you will raise width and height for thumbnail it would become dull,
I also have a blog [tech4way](http://tech4way.com)

where i have done many possibilities to change size of thumbnail but it did not work